# Google App Engine NullPointerException after deploying

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

We have made no changes whatsoever to any configuration files and this project used to work fine, but just recently upon deploying our Java backend to Google App Engine we get a strange error message below which is not even in our code.  We have searched a lot, but we still have no idea why this has started happening.

```
/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:100)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:657)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:619)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:589)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You made a very big change - deploying to GAE.  That's the source of the error.

Comment: Why did you re-deploy if there were no changes?

Comment: Is your backend using the Backends API by any chance?

Comment: We did make changes only to our Java files.  (Only small logic changes.)  We deployed the same way that we always deploy (Build menu --> Deploy Module to App Engine...)  Why should it be any different this time around?!

Comment: We are not using the Backends API.

Comment: @duffymo we always have deployed to GAE.  What do you mean?

Comment: You did make changes.  Why would you redeploy unless you did?

Comment: @duffymo You're right!  Upon checking again, I see this unintended change in the build.gradle:

`providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'` and `compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'`

Comment: So kind of you to let me know.  Lots of people here love telling me when I'm wrong; gratifying to hear when I might be helpful.  Thank you.  @Dan Cornilescu said the same thing, so he should be cited as well.